# Fire trigger only when rows are updated

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a command to execute inside oracle triggers after a modification of a table.
I need this command to run once (even if there is 100 rows updated), and only when there is rows updated.

`FOR EACH ROW` allow to be sure to send the command only when there is rows updated, so how could I stop its execution after the first loop ?

Comment: You are looking for a statement level trigger: `for each statement`

Comment: A statement-level trigger will be fired once, but even if no rows are updated... I need to be sure to send my command only if a row is actually updated

Comment: Then use a compound trigger that counts the number of modified rows: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#CIHGJFAB

Comment: It worked with compound trigger thanks ! I have a concern when inserting or updating huge number of lines, the process will have to loop on million of rows when in my case the fact that one single line has changed is enough to run my process

Answer (score 1):

It looks you're going to use `compound trigger`. In `for each row` section you need to collect `rowid`s to update and in `after statement` run whole update

Comment: Compound trigger worked ! But I dont need to collect something, I need to be sure that at least one line changed and run a single time a refresh command.

Comment: @DJozef I wrote about collecting to have count of changed rows by comparing `:new <> :old` to trigger code when real update happen not update to the same value. But if this is enough for you I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use global package variable.

1) Reset it to null in before update statement trigger.

2) Save values/inc counter in for each row trigger

3) do final check in after update statement trigger and fire your logic inly once regardless number of affected rows